# Are spring boot feign configuration beans abusing the @bean annotation?

Tags: spring-boot, visual-studio-code, spring-cloud-feign

I probably don't have a great grasp of @Beans in general, so please excuse any ignorance here. I'm sure I'm misunderstanding something.

I have a pretty simple Feign configuration class:

```
public class SillyAuthFeignConfig {
    @Bean
    public RequestInterceptor sillyAuthRequestInterceptor() {
        return requestTemplate ->
            requestTemplate.header(
                "Authorization",
                "This is silly auth!"
            );
    }
}
```

My understanding of `@Bean` is that spring boot will spot the annotation, run the function, and drop the Bean of type `RequestInterceptor` in its pool of beans. (oversimplified I'm sure)

However I believe the class that the `@Bean` resides in also needs the `@Configuration` annotation, else spring wont spot the bean and create it.

But since I don't want this feign config applying globally I have not added the `@Configuration` annotation.

So given that my above class is NOT annotated with `@Configuration`, does feign do some sort of reflection, looking for methods with the `@Bean` annotation? And if so, isn't that kind of abusing the `@Bean` annotation?

Disclaimer: I am using vscode to do my spring boot dev, and it is warning me:

> '@Configuration' is missing on a class defining Spring Beans. vscode-spring-boot(MISSING_CONFIGURATION_ANNOTATION)

... which led me down this path. Who is at fault? Is vscode just being overzealous, or is feign misusing the @Bean annotation.